# Community wiki'zed by only one contributor

Tags: support, edits, answers, community-wiki

I just did quite some research on one question, editing the answer multiple times.

Here's my answer: [How to create a shadow around a background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17514677/how-to-create-a-shadow-around-a-background-image/17515073#17515073)

I'm the sole contributor to it, but because I managed to edit it more than 10 times, it has become a CW.

Now, people might upvote it and accept, but, because it's a CW, I won't get any rep even though I'm sole contributor.

Is this really intended?

Not being greedy or anything, but I actually would love some reputation from the question, because it involves some great research.

Comment: that is how it works, yes.

Comment: Assuming all your edits were significant (not just attempts at bumps) you can flag and request a mod de-community wikis

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [This post about CW posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/226203), ten edits by the original author is deliberately a trigger for CW status on a post, which means that at the very least, this behavior isn't a bug.

Comment: Woops, didn't knew it.

Comment: @joltmode: You can however, flag it to ask for it to be unCWed. Just custom flag it.

Comment: I already flagged before asking here, got already unCWed.

Comment: Note for any new readers stumbling across this old Q&A: the automatic conversion of posts to community wiki due to too many edits, as described here, [was removed in 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228947). The only ways in which a question or an answer can now become a community wiki are described in the linked [FAQ answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741).